# how to change the text in menu cascade tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
self.root = root
self.root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
self.root.title("Client")
self.menu_bar = Menu(self.root)
self.file_menu = Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff=0)
self.file_menu.add_command(label="Log in", command=self.show_log_in)
self.file_menu.add_command(label="Reconnect", command=self.reconnect)
self.file_menu.entryconfig(1, state=DISABLED)
self.file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.root.destroy)
self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.file_menu)
```

I am trying to change the text in the "File" cascade to different word. What is the command for that?
I tried:

```
self.menu_bar.entryconfig(0, label="Different word")
```

But it doesn't work. (raised an error).

Comment: What do you mean the text? Just change `File` to a different word, unless you meant something else.

Comment: I want a button to change the text during the program run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `File` `cascade` is the 1 indexed entry. This works for me:

```
self.menu_bar.entryconfig(1, label="Different word")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
label_text = StringVar()
self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label=label_text, menu=self.file_menu)
self.label_text.set("File")

def change_label(self,text):
    self.label_text.set(text)
```

**Disclaimer:** I did not test this code.

Comment: It doesn't work. It prints PY_VAR0 instead of file. I tried to fix it and write label_text.get() but it doesn't update the text.

Comment: Did you remember to update the GUI with `self.root.update`?

Comment: still doesn't change the text.

Comment: try: label=label_text.get()  instead of label=label_text

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate the button you need to have a command that calls a function that will change the text. For example:

```
btn3 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Create Shortcut", bg=gridcolor7, state="normal",  
    width=btnw, height=btnh, command=lambda k='new text': arm_shortcut_command(k))  
btn3.grid(row=r,column=c)

def arm_shortcut_command(k):
    <code to change menu text>
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change any item whit the call item's label.
for example from your code, I change the name of "Log in" to "Different word" and state of "Reconnect" to disable in python3.

```
self.file_menu.entryconfig("Log in",label="Different word")
self.file_menu.entryconfig("Reconnect",state=DISABLE)
```